# Disable inline stack trace for failed tests in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I run a JUnit test that fails, it fills my entire editor window with the stack trace. It becomes impossible to see the code for the actual test, because it's buried underneath the stack trace.

I'm not sure if it's VS Code that's changed something, or the Test Runner for Java extension (recommended by VS Code) that has changed. Previously, running a test would open a Test Explorer as a separate tab. Any failures would still show the stack trace, but it was very easy to compare the stack trace to the code side by side. Is there a way to re-enable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Start from the `0.31.0`, the `Test Runner for Java` extension migrates to the [VS Code native testing API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107467). That's why you observed such big UX changes.

Now, if you don't want to show those test messages automatically after running, you can set the setting `testing.automaticallyOpenPeekView` to `never`.

Comment: The `testing.automaticallyOpenPeekView` setting does nothing, I still get the stack trace for failed tests with it set to `never`.

Comment: Please file an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues. We will consider how to improve the UX

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue put in vscode/java-test: [[Request] Hide the JUnit Callstack from the stacktrace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1281).

You may comment there to describe your needs and follow up it for solution.

Comment: Thank you, I am now following that issue.